# Finding root of a function containing an array using uniroot.all

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the roots of a function like this

```
f <- function(x) {
    sum( tanh(Carray + x) ) - x
}

library(rootSolve)
roots <- uniroot.all(f,c(0,1))
```

where x is a scalar and Carray is an array. The problem seems to be that uniroot.all sends to f a whole array of x'es at once, and then R gets confused about doing Carray+x (warning: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length").

Function f works as intended when x is a scalar. I am not sure how to vectorize f so that I can pass to it an array of x'es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we knew the size of `Carray`, it would maybe be possible to vectorize `f` more naturally, but for a general `Carray` you could use `Vectorize`:

```
roots <- uniroot.all(Vectorize(f), c(0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, example:

```
f <- function(x) {
    sum(tanh(y+x))/100-x
}
vf <- Vectorize(f)

y=runif(100,-1,1)

f(x=0.5)
f(x=-0.5)
vf(x=1:2)

uniroot.all(vf,c(-.99,.99))
```